# Cannot see variable change from test - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a variable that should have its value changed depending on whether I login successfully or not. However, from my test I cannot see this change and simply get 'undefined' returned.

This variable **DOES** change when I am actually using the app, displaying 'Either username or password were incorrect' when logging in with obviously the wrong details.

Is there any reason why I cannot see the updated `errorMessage`?

**UPDATE**
I have placed a bunch of console.log messages throughout the flow of the functions and it appears that it makes it as far as ** const body in the auth > login() file** but it doesn't appear to be returning anything.

Comment: That is probably because you are using `HttpClientTestingModule` which never makes the real `http` request to your api. You could also mock the http response instead to return `no token` in your response.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Could you give me code example of how I would do this? I'm a n00b :-(

Comment: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/mocking-http-request-with-httpclient-in-angular

Comment: I have already tested the Auth.service in this way. I am wanting to test the login.component's login function... Are you saying that I should do the call for auth.login in this way and then return something like that?

Comment: Yes, when you are testing only the component behavior, it is ideal to mock the http requests.

Comment: Ah ok. I get it now. I just cant visualise how I would check the `errorMessage` variable in the `login.component` after mocking the `auth.service` response?

Comment: Your test case will not change. It seems appropriate what you are doing now. Only thing that you have to do is mocking of `login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply mock the `login()` service and return error from it. No need to make a call to real `login()` as well, since you are only testing the `errorMessage` that is being set inside the component file.

```
it('should call login when passed valid form with incorrect credentials but return error', () => {
    // spy on login() and throw error from there
    spyOn(component.authService, 'login').and.throwError('Unable to get Token'); 
    component.onSubmit(validFormBadCreds);
    expect(component.errorMessage).toEqual('Either username or password were incorrect');
}
```

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. I was trying to implement what the link you sent did XD. The `and.throwError()` was literally throwing an error and causing the test to fail there?

Comment: It throws the error, because you are validating the error scenario. You know that username, password combination is wrong and you have already tested `login()` service which should be working fine. What you should verify now is, whether your component method's error block was invoked and `errorMessage` is set or not. If error is thrown, then test case should pass. This is the logic for unit testing.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going with .and.returnValue(of({...})) in the end